# Insert based on dropdownlist value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Well, based on dropdown value I need the values in my form to be inserted into the Database table.. But it is not working now..

This is my aspx page-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" class="box" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>Confirm Order</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Tentative Order</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

And then I used switch..

```
switch (DropDownList1.SelectedValue) 
{ 
    case "Confirm Order": 
        ... INSERT 
    break; 
    case "Tentative Order": 
        ...Insert 
    break;
}
```

But its giving an error-

`No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem to a known managed provider native type.`

What is the right way of doing it?

Comment: You have to convert the selected value to String

Comment: .SelectedValue property is already a string.

Comment: show your insert code - the error is there

Comment: Insert code was wrong.. There was one more DropDownList where I had to Convert it to .ToString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using:

**DropDownList1.SelectedValue**

or

**DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value**

or

**DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text**

in your INSERT Queries.

(And not DropDownList1.SelectedItem - this will give ListItem)

Comment: Correct :)  But I had to use ".ToString();" to one of my dropdownlist in my insert stmt.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
switch (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
{
    //Rest Remains the same
}
```

Comment: Then put what is in your insert query.

Comment: This is wrong. The ToString() on the SelectedItem will give you the ListItem type's ToString(), not the actual value!

Comment: @FarligOpptreden: Corrected. Look.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is you are mapping your DDL to the class "box", and in your switch/case statement you aren't using this mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You may Take ddl.SelectedItem.Value as a reference and pass the value into the required methods.

String tempString = yourDDL.SelectedItem.Value

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ID value
eg.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="Confirm Order" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

And switch

```
switch (DropDownList1.SelectedValue) 
{ 
    case "1": 
        ... INSERT 
}
```